# Share Data Between View Controller and Container View

Tags: swift, uicontainerview

I have a view controller that has a segue to a second view controller, and I passed some data to the second one in prepare for segue.
The problem is: the second view controller has a container view which I need to share that data with. I tried using prepare for segue but it didn't work in this case.

**Update:**

View Controller code:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController, ContainerViewDelegate {

   var myContainerView = ContainerView()
   var id: String!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        id = "123"
        myContainerView.delegate = self
   }

   func initialize() -> String {
        return id
   }
}
```

Container view code:

```
protocol ContainerViewDelegate {
   func initialize() -> String
}

class ContainerView: UICollectionViewController {

   var delegate: ContainerViewDelegate!
   var id: String!
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       id = delegate.initialize()
       print(id)
   }
}
```

I get error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` at the line: `id = delegate.initialize()`

Comment: Use the `Delegate` pattern. Google it.

Comment: I don't even know what a 'container view' is.

Comment: @shallowThought Thanks. I did try to use Delegate, but I got some nil exceptions and I think I didn't use it the right way. Can you please provide me the structure to steps of how to use Delegate?

Comment: @nouf Please post what you have tried and where you ran into "some nil exceptions", so we can help you pinpoint the issue.

Comment: @ElTomato 'container view' is the view you use in Xcode Storyboard to hook child view controllers

Comment: Try call `super.viewDidLoad()` after `id = "123"`.

Comment: @Jonny Same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track to setup the delegate.

In Storyboard:

- create a Segue of type `Embed Segue` from the `ContainerView` to the ViewController to embed.
- Select the segue and set a `Identifier`.

In Code, in `prepareForSegue()`:

- Set the `myContainerView` propert
- Set the delegate

  ```
  class ViewController: UITableViewController, ContainerViewDelegate {
      var myContainerView:ContainerView? // we do initialize it in prepareForSegue()
      var id: String!

      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          id = "123"
          // myContainerView.delegate = self //myContainerView is nil here. We set it in prepareForSegue
      }

      func initialize() -> String {
          return id
      }

      let embedSegueID = "the identifier you set to your embed segue in Storyboard"

      override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
          if (segue.identifier == embedSegueID) {
              let dvc = segue.destination as! ContainerView
              // Now you have a pointer to EmbeddedViewController.
              // You can save the reference to it, or pass data to it.
              myContainerView = dvc
              myContainerView.delegate = self
          }
          print(segue.identifier)
      }
  }
  ```

---

If you want to pass data from your ViewController to AnotherViewController which is embedded in your destinationViewController (how I understand your question), I would:

- pass it to destinationViewController as in the example above (prepareForSegue)
- than pass it to AnotherViewController in `viewWillAppear()` from within destinationViewController.

In this case, how I understand your usecase, you do not need the delegate and can remove all delegate related code (`initialize`, the `ContainerViewDelegate` protocol, the property `var delegate: ContainerViewDelegate!` and all calls to it.

Comment: This is a great solution. Thank you

Comment: Welcome! I added one more thought at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use prepare for segue and send everything you want to second Controller ...

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:   AnyObject?) {
    // get a reference to the second view controller
    let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController

    // set a variable in the second view controller to pass
    secondViewController.data = data
    }
```

Comment: This will not work in case of ContainerView being the second view container. because ContainerView's ViewDidLoad will be called before prepareForSegue

Comment: you can set data when viewDidAppear called from second view controller to container

Answer (score 0):

Two way:

1. In your second view controller, override `prepare(for:sender:)`

   ```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

       if segue.identifier == "loadContainerView" { // replace with your segue identifier
            let childViewControllerController = segue.destination
            // pass data
       }
   }
   ```
2. In your second view controller, use `childViewControllers` to access your container views' controller.

   ```
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewDidAppear(animated)
       if let childViewController = childViewControllers.first {
           // pass your data
       }
   }
   ```

Sample Project:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/he97ldzhav2non3/ContainerViewTest.zip?dl=0